# Best beginners guide to sound/audio

Tags: audio, sound

I'm trying to learn audio programming, but am struggling with the basics of audio.

Audio programming is new to me (I'm a C/C++ developer with over 30 years of experience), but I don't have any background in sound/audio or DSP.

I'm learning ad-hoc, through various websites. Things I need to know are sampling, envelope, sweeps, length counters, pulse waves, triangle waves, delta modulation, PCM, etc.

Is there some kind of definitive book that I should start with, given my background? I don't really need to understand advanced sound processing, just something thats beginner and somewhat easy to digest.

Comment: It is always useful to have a "project" to drive your learning. In the meantime, you might want to have a look at [this search](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=books) for many relevant posts with very good responses.

Comment: Beginning with or without a knowledge of calculus, linear algebra and complex arithmetic or analysis?  Graduate or undergraduate level?  Completely different "beginner" resources depending on the level indicated by those answers.

Comment: This [answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/29228/8202) might be somehow related.

Comment: Happy new year, and a reminder that your question and its answers require some action (votes, acceptance)

Answer (score 3):

In general you can divide the audio books into the following categories:

1. Audio Engineering
2. Audio Programming
3. Audio Signal Processing and Coding
4. Digital Signal processing

For your exclusive requirement (that fall into cat-2) I highly recommend the following book: **The Audio Programming Book_BOULANGER_MIT**

Comment: I also heard a professional developer in audio dsp recommended this book.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start from signal processing tools, [Spectral Audio Signal Processing](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/sasp.html) is a comprehensive source for Fourier and filtering related techniques in audio.

With a C++ twist, you can look at:

- [The Synthesis ToolKit in C++ (STK)](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/),
- [Aquila, an open source and cross-platform DSP (Digital Signal Processing) library written in C++](http://aquila-dsp.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You ‍say you are a ‌‌‌developer of C/C++, I think the "Digital Signal Processing using MATLAB" writen by Proakis, Vinay is very useful book.Since Matlab is a piece of cake for a C developer. This book contains filtering and all techniques in audio processing i.e frequency domain, wavelet domain, coefficients domain (MFCC's, etc.).
Other resource is the great website: [DSP Related](http://www.dsprelated.com)

Comment: Please explain more!